# Remove product from CustomCollection - shopify

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

I am trying to connect product with custom collection using shopify API with the help of https://docs.shopify.com/api/customcollection

I can add product to the collection using

```
  PUT /admin/custom_collections/#{id}.json
{
  "custom_collection": {
    "id": 841564295,
    "collects": [
      {
        "product_id": 921728736,
        "position": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 841564295,
        "position": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But, I need to remove a product from the collection.is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shopify: Remove product from collection via API call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710211/shopify-remove-product-from-collection-via-api-call)

Comment: @bknights That answer is for collection,this is custom collection,read the example carefully

Comment: Actually you might want to review that answer again. Custom Collection uses the collect as a join to products. If you want to remove the product from the collection you delete its collect.

Comment: @bknights Then what about other products in that collection?

Comment: Please read the solution given and then review the Shopify API docs. The question in my link shows how to remove a single production from a collection by deleting a "collect".  My answer indicates how to find that collect id. If you need to remove multiple products from a collection you'd do that multiple times. For efficiency if you have a list of products to remove from a single collection you could use `GET /admin/collects.json?collection_id=841564295` to get all the relevant collectids. You'd still have to remove products one-by-one. See https://docs.shopify.com/api/collect

Comment: @bknights Thank you ,My problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Any collection, Custom Collection or Smart Collection, is governed by sets of relations between a product and the collection. In order to remove a product from a collection you have to indeed remove the relation between them, in simple words destroy the collect.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710211/shopify-remove-product-from-collection-via-api-call) mentioned by [bknights](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3806017/bknights) is right process for your question.

Answer (score 0):

This link provides you the complete detail about the collect which is a relation between the product and collection .

You Just Need the collect_id if you are saving it while creating the collection . save that collect_id while creating collect and you can delete the collect using api given in this link.

https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference/products/collect#destroy-2021-07

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you. Also, try to sum up your answer in case the link stops working in the future